# Magento REST API / Apache and "Content-Type header is empty"

Tags: rest-api, .htaccess, apache2

Has anyone noticed this error message "Content-Type header is empty" when POST-ing to Magento REST API? I'm using Postman for testing and very-very surely I'm sending the Content-Type header along with my request. So something cuts it off in between. Can it be misconfigured Apache / .htaccess? Never seen that problem with nginx before.

The error is thrown by Mage_Api2_Model_Request, in the very early stage of API request.

Answer (score 3):

Allright, after messing around with Apache config I found the following:
I had missing "-pass-header Content-Type" from fastcgi.conf
Make sure you have it on this line:

```
FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi -host 127.0.0.1:9000 -pass-header  Authorization -pass-header Content-Type
```

Comment: Not working for me. I am passing FastCGI requests to PHP-FPM. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

If you use another way of proxying requests from Apache to PHP-FPM, you can add this to your Apache vhost config:

```
# Pass extra http headers to PHP-FPM
SetEnvIfNoCase ^Authorization$ "(.+)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
SetEnvIfNoCase ^Content-Type$ "(.+)" HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE=$1
```